# type 'GeoPoint' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am try google maps flutter with firestore but there is something going wrong.

Here is my code

```
class StoreMap extends StatelessWidget {
  const StoreMap({
    Key key,
    @required this.documents,
    @required this.initialPosition,
    @required this.mapController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;
  final LatLng initialPosition;
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: initialPosition,
        zoom: 12,
      ),
      markers: documents
          .map((document) => Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId(document['placeId']),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(_pinkHue),
                position: LatLng(
                  document['location'].latitude,
                  document['location'].longitude,
                ),
                infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: document['name'],
                  snippet: document['address'],
                ),
              ))
          .toSet(),
      onMapCreated: (mapController) {
        this.mapController.complete(mapController);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

type 'GeoPoint' is not a subtype of type 'String'

**The Firestore is look like**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks like it is `MarkerId(document['placeID'])`, it needs to be a String.

You can try with `MarkerId(document['placeID'].toString())` or generate your own custom string based on the position of the marker.

Watch out for your `placeId` instead of `placeID`.

Comment: Thanks for Answering. But there is something going wrong. The getter 'latitude' was called on null. Here, is the full code [link](https://github.com/brandon-irl/CloudNextFlutterMapsDemo/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Comment: @richie Looks like your Firestore holds `placeID`, not `placeId`

Comment: @richie Shouldn't you be using `document['placeID']` instead of  `document['location']` ?

Comment: Thanks @Martyns, Thanks for your suggestion. But there is new issue and it is : Only one marker is place on the map instead of all.

Comment: @richie I don't really know how to help you there as I have never used the Google Maps plugin. Make sure you are getting more than one document in your Widget.